# Removing the dashed blue box around a folded code header in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I've looked through the configuration menus several times, but haven't been able to find a way to change the color of or remove altogether the dashed blue box that appears around a folded code header (while keeping the folding itself).  Is it not possible or have I just missed it?

Comment: I don’t think this is currently possible (I can’t find anything either). You may ask a question or create a feature request on [texstudio.sourceforge.net](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Just a question: why don't you like it? It is a good way to see a hide block.

Comment: With the other syntax highlighting and arrows it's just unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not configurable in TeXstudio.